# GetHashCode в качестве ключа

Tags: c#

У меня есть SortedList, где в качестве ключа  идет int, а value строка.

```
public void AddElements()
{
    int collectionLength = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    for(int key = 0; key < collectionLength; key++)
    internalSortedList.Add(key, RandomClass.CreateRandomString());
}
```

Вопрос, как задать в качестве ключа GetHashCode?

Comment: `GetHashCode` от чего? Можно написать `key.GetHashCode()`, но это не будет иметь смысла, т.к. хэш код от `int` - это само значение `int`, но можно сделать что-то в духе `String value = RandomClass.CreateRandomString();
   internalSortedList.Add(value.GetHashCode(), value);`

Comment: спасибо за ответ, помогло) видимо не совсем верно изложил мысль,но вы правы, что нет смысла брать хэшкод от int

Comment: Окей, продублировал в ответ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно написать `key.GetHashCode()`, но это не будет иметь смысла, т.к. хэш код от `int` - это само значение `int`, но можно сделать что-то в духе:

```
String value = RandomClass.CreateRandomString();
internalSortedList.Add(value.GetHashCode(), value);
```